# Electrical outlet that has 2 white wires, 1 black, 1 red, and a ground. Does it matter which white goes where?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I did some searching on the site, but I wasn't able to find anything about this. That being said, I have an electrical outlet that has 2 white wires, 1 black, 1 red, and a ground. I know the red line is to the light switch. What I don't know is which white wire was connected alongside the the black or red wires. Does it matter which white wire is connected along with the black wire? Red wire? Being in a hurry, I didn't pay any attention to what wires were connected on either side of each other before I snipped them.

I also know that the outlet is in the middle of a run as the power to the outlets on the other side of the room lost power when I disconnected the power outlet in question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Was half of this outlet controlled by the switch and the other half always live? On the old outlet, are the tabs between the hot terminals missing or intact? Between the neutral (white side) missing or intact?

Comment: That.  Also, stop snipping wires unless you have really excess length in there... , twist them out of the old backstab one at a time, or unscrew the screw.

Comment: Does one of the white wires happen to have a red stripe on it?

Comment: Also, can you post a photo of the inside of the box in question?

Comment: most likely the two white wires should be connected together; they aren't two wires, they are a splice.

Comment: If back stabs are used don't snip them there is usually a slot you can use a scrap piece of 14 gauge solid wire or a small screwdriver to release the back stabs and remove the wire.